# Resizing HTML table in Outlook body won't work

Tags: python, html, pandas, html-table, outlook

I am using pandas dataframe to retrieve data that I am parsing to outlook email body after I format it with pretty_html_table package. I have managed dealing with all the necessities including parsing the table. However, I am unable to resize the table, I just need it smaller.

I have tried various html codes around the web but I am getting no changes in the email body. May someone help me how to scale down the whole table in my case?

Thank you very much!

My code:

```
# Taking email, subject, body from the excel
Email_Preset_Source = xw.Book(R"C:\Users\mxs5760\Desktop\EmailsDistribution\Germany on hold.xlsx")
To = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('D4').value
CC = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('L6').value
Subject = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('L4').value

body_text1 = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('L9').value
body_text2 = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('L10').value
body_text3 = Email_Preset_Source.sheets['Email Distribution Settings'].range('L11').value


# Building and formatting table
body_table = build_table(TESTFiltering1, 'green_light',font_family = 'Arial', font_size = 'small', text_align = 'center')

# Creating Outlook Object
outlook = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Outlook.Application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = To
mail.CC = CC
mail.Subject = Subject
mail.GetInspector

# Code for activating default signature
signature = mail.HTMLBody 
mail.HTMLBody = (body_text1 + "<br><br>" + body_text2 + "<br><br>" + body_text3 + "<br><br>" + '<table style="table-layout:fixed;">' + '<table style="width:40%">' + '<td width="2">' + body_table + signature)


#print(mail.HTMLBody)

mail.Display()
```

Comment: Hello Marek! I wrote this library and there is no resizing options as of today. You can play with the color, the size of the font, the family of the font and the alignment of the text. The library is public on github, anyone is welcome to add their inputs!

Comment: Thanks for the information RenauV! I have modified my table with some direct HTML modifications in the end but would be definitely nice to have that option in pretty html table :)